# Question about literary devices (probably personification)

Tags: literary-device, literary-english, personification

Is there  any literary device? I suspect that the part with "relationship" is connected with personification.
From: https://www.britishtours.com/greenwich-tours.

> The Museum packs a treasure house of maritime history inside its rooms - ordnance, artefacts, records and relics of the island's long relationship with all the seas of the world.

Comment: Is there an actual treasure house inside the museum?

Comment: Probably metaphorically? As it contains a lot of things of historical value

Comment: 'Long' here is also arguably a metaphorical usage. 'Packs' here certainly is.

Comment: You need to be more specific about which part of the sentence you're asking about. Comments are referring to different ones.

Comment: It's filled with personification so common that it loses its metaphor.

Comment: Merriam Webster: pack b: to fill completelyfans packed the stadium//The only personification is making the museum into an agent that packs stuff into the museum.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it's [synecdoche](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/synecdoche) - using "island" to refer to its inhabitants.